# Iterating over XML with Nokogiri in ERB leaves '0' char at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, erb

In my Rails-Application i want to process some XML to use in a ERB-view. When iterating over the XML, theres a random "0" at the end of every "each"-iteration, i don't know where that comes from and how to get rid of it.

The XML comes from a Database-Query in the Controller, the XML is then stored in '@template':

```
@template = Nokogiri::XML(@formclass.first[:definition])
```

the XML looks something like this:

```
<form-template>
  <fields>
    <field type="radio-group" label="This Label 1" inline="true" class="assessment_value" name="frage1">
      <option label="Immer" value="1">Immer</option>
      <option label="Meistens" value="2">Meistens</option>
    </field>
    <field type="radio-group" label="This other label" inline="true" class="assessment_value" name="frage2">
      <option label="Mehr als einmal am Tag" value="1">Mehr als einmal am Tag</option>
      <option label="Einmal am Tag" value="2">Einmal am Tag</option>
    </field>
  </fields>
</form-template>
```

in the erb-view:

```
<%= @template.css('field').each do |field_node| -%>
  foo
<% end -%>
```

and the result is this:

> foo foo **0**

when iterating in the controller, theres no "0":

```
@template.css('field').each do |field_node|
  logger.debug("foo")
end
```

> foo
>   foo

What am i doing wrong? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you output the whole result of `each`, while you probably want to output the *iterated values*:

```
<% @template.css('field').each do |field_node| %>
  <%= raw(field_node.text) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: right, so "foo" is not the output i actually want ;-)

when i use your suggested code, theres still a "0" at the end tho...

Comment: ... but it helped! so my mistake was using `<%= .. -%>` , i changed that to `<% .. %>` and now the "0" is gone for good. thank you!